# Display All Non-Used Plugins

Tags: plugins, functions, multisite

My company currently has a multisite of about 20 sites, and growing every day. We're trying to go through the plugins and set standards. IE, forms use plugin X. However, we have not found a single way to go through and systematically show which plugins aren't even used.

Is there a function that can show us the used, or unused plugins? I have tried searching everything I can think of and cannot for the life of me find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it cannot be easily determined whether the various plugins you have installed - out of the 23,499 available in the WordPress repo, as of this writing - are currently doing anything.

If a plugin is activated, it is "being used". Whether or not a given plugin is actually doing anything is an entirely different matter. Since plugins can do a near-infinite number of different things, it would be near-impossible for there to be a way test all past and future plugins to see if they are doing anything.

As an example, say you have a shortcode plugin that you use with `[some_shortcode]`. You could search your posts for that shortcode, and if your search comes up empty, you know it's not being used. But other plugins do entirely different things, like caching content, adding SEO, enhancing Social-ness in your blog, changing your footer text, etc. How would you create a test to determine if they are "being used"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmu-plugin-stats/screenshots/

> Provides info to site admins as to which plugins are activated
>   sitewide, and which blogs plugins are activated on.

This plugin is using `get_plugins()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins

and fetches `get_option('active_plugins')` for each blog to compare.

It uses `switch_to_blog()` on each blog so it might be slower on large multisites, but I think this function got faster after the wordpress 3.5 update, according to

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21459
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5